# Seleccionar registro desde sql y mostrar en una tabla html

Tags: php, html, sql

Quiero saber cómo poder seleccionar registros individualmente de una tabla en sql mediante su id, y que por cada id que ingrese en el input, aparezca la información en una tabla en html.

Este programa que llevo hasta ahora selecciona el id de una tabla en sql y muestra solo un registro en una tabla en html.

Lo que quiero hacer es que la tabla en html se guarden todos los registros que quiera meter, supongo que en un arreglo se podría hacer ya que la única función de la tabla en html es que se muestre en pantalla.

Hasta ahora el programa solo puede mostrar un registro en la tabla:

```html
<?php
require_once "scripts.php"; //conexion de bd

$valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];
//$mensaje = "";
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    if(empty($valueToSearch)){
        
        echo "$mensaje";
    } else{
    // search in all table columns
    // using concat mysql function
    $query = "SELECT * FROM bitacora.bitacora_tarjeta_ruta WHERE CONCAT(`id`) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
    }    
}

// function to connect and execute the query
function filterTable($query)
{
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bitacora");
    $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    return $filter_Result;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SCANNER</title>
        <style>
            table,tr,th,td{
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" name="valueToSearch" placeholder="INGRESA EL ID"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="search" value="Ingresar Dato"><br><br>
            
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>COLADA</th>
                    <th>CLIENTE</th>
                </tr>

      <!-- populate table from mysql database -->
                <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['tarjeta1'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['tarjeta2'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endwhile;?>
            </table>
        </form>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Podrias usar Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar algo como esto: 
HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form accept-charset="utf-8" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="busqueda" id="busqueda" value="" placeholder="" maxlength="30" autocomplete="off" />
        <!--O puedes usar-->
        <input type="text" name="busqueda" id="busqueda" value="" placeholder="" maxlength="30" autocomplete="off"
            onKeyUp="buscar();" />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#resultadoBusqueda").html('<p>JQUERY VACIO</p>');
    });

    function buscar() {
        var textoBusqueda = $("input#busqueda").val();

         if (textoBusqueda != "") {
            $.post("buscar.php", {valorBusqueda: textoBusqueda}, function(mensaje) {
                $("#resultadoBusqueda").html(mensaje);
             }); 
         } else { 
            $("#resultadoBusqueda").html('<p>JQUERY VACIO</p>');
            };
    };
```

PHP:

```
//Archivo de conexión a la base de datos
require('conexion.php');

//Variable de búsqueda
$consultaBusqueda = $_POST['valorBusqueda'];

//Filtro anti-XSS
$caracteres_malos = array("<", ">", "\"", "'", "/", "<", ">", "'", "/");
$caracteres_buenos = array("& lt;", "& gt;", "& quot;", "& #x27;", "& #x2F;", "& #060;", "& #062;", "& #039;", "& #047;");
$consultaBusqueda = str_replace($caracteres_malos, $caracteres_buenos, $consultaBusqueda);

//Variable vacía (para evitar los E_NOTICE)
$mensaje = "";


//Comprueba si $consultaBusqueda está seteado
if (isset($consultaBusqueda)) {

    //Selecciona todo de la tabla mmv001 
    //donde el nombre sea igual a $consultaBusqueda, 
    //o el apellido sea igual a $consultaBusqueda, 
    //o $consultaBusqueda sea igual a nombre + (espacio) + apellido
    $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM mmv001
    WHERE nombre COLLATE UTF8_SPANISH_CI LIKE '%$consultaBusqueda%' 
    OR apellido COLLATE UTF8_SPANISH_CI LIKE '%$consultaBusqueda%'
    OR CONCAT(nombre,' ',apellido) COLLATE UTF8_SPANISH_CI LIKE '%$consultaBusqueda%'
    ");

    //Obtiene la cantidad de filas que hay en la consulta
    $filas = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);

    //Si no existe ninguna fila que sea igual a $consultaBusqueda, entonces mostramos el siguiente mensaje
    if ($filas === 0) {
        $mensaje = "<p>No hay ningún usuario con ese nombre y/o apellido</p>";
    } else {
        //Si existe alguna fila que sea igual a $consultaBusqueda, entonces mostramos el siguiente mensaje
        echo 'Resultados para <strong>'.$consultaBusqueda.'</strong>';

        //La variable $resultado contiene el array que se genera en la consulta, así que obtenemos los datos y los mostramos en un bucle
        while($resultados = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
            $nombre = $resultados['nombre'];
            $apellido = $resultados['apellido'];
            $edad = $resultados['edad'];

            //Output
            $mensaje .= '
            <p>
            <strong>Nombre:</strong> ' . $nombre . '<br>
            <strong>Apellido:</strong> ' . $apellido . '<br>
            <strong>Edad:</strong> ' . $edad . '<br>
            </p>';

        };//Fin while $resultados

    }; //Fin else $filas

};//Fin isset $consultaBusqueda

//Devolvemos el mensaje que tomará jQuery
echo $mensaje;
?>
```

Espero te ayude, claro esta debes adaptarlo a tú solución.